# Pass Object of class to another class using robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I want pass object of one class to another class.
Below is the code which I have tried.

```
 *** Settings ***
Documentation 
Library       helper.confHelp.ConfHelper    ${confJson}
Library       demoHelp.demo.py
*** Variables ***
${confJson}   conf/help.json
*** Test Cases ***
[Documentation]
[Tag]
${configObj}    Get Library Instance     helper.confHelp.ConfHelper
demoHelp.demo.Demo    ${configObj}                    # this is the 
another class and pass the object of ConfHelper
Log To Console    Start
methodOfDemoClass
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is you observe? i.e. error messages?

Comment: What does this do that is different from what you expect it to do? If you want to pass `${configObj}` to `methodOfDemoClass`, have you tried passing it like you pass data to any other keyword (eg: `methodOfDemoClass  ${configObj}`?

Comment: what do you mean "I stuck"? It looks like you're passing it. Why do you think it's not working?